# How to remove elements from a Python dictionary based on elements in a list?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of tuples:

```
lst=[(6, 'C'), (6, 'H'), (2, 'C'), (2, 'H')]
```

And a dictionary:

```
dct={'6C': (6, 'C'), '6H': (6, 'H'), '9D': (9, 'D'), '10D': (10, 'D'), '11S': (11, 'S'), '2C': (2, 'C'), '2H': (2, 'H')}
```

How can I remove the elements from the dictionary that are in the list? In this example my desired output would be:

```
dct2={'9D': (9, 'D'), '10D': (10, 'D'), '11S': (11, 'S')}
```

Comment: 1. iterate over list.  2. concatenate list pairs into key.  3. use key to remove element from dictionary.

Comment: is there a relation between the key and value of your dct, I see joining value will lead to the corresponding key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use a dictionary comprehension to map the keys with the values that aren't found within a list:

```
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in old_dict.items() if v not in the_list} # filter from the list
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Python 2 try this:

```
for key, value in dct.items():
    if value in lst:
        del dct[key]
```

EDIT:

A solution that works in both Python 2 and 3:

```
dict((key, value) for key, value in dct.items() if value not in lst)
```

Comment: I'd edit your first solution to iterate a copy of `dict.items()`

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Well, that speaks for its quality, I guess

Comment: @MalikBrahimi Iterating a copy of `dict.items()` is not necessary in Python 2

Comment: Are you sure about that? Mutation while iteration is a no-no regardless of version.

Comment: Using `copy` on `dict.items()` would add nothing in regard to safety in Python 2 as it returns a list of tuples already, not an iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [`valfilter` function from toolz](http://toolz.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#toolz.dicttoolz.valfilter):

```
from toolz import valfilter
valfilter(lst.__contains__, dct)
```

Comment: Using `__dunder__` methods directly is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would make the `lst` set before filtering out elements, since it is data structure which let's you test if element is present more efficiently.

```
purge_set = set(lst)
dict(filter(lambda (k, v): v not in purge_set, dct.iteritems()))
```

Comment: In practice you have go a long way to see any performance difference for __contains__ between a tuple and a set. For large datasets avoiding the loop would better.